# VSCode Native Debug display asm layout to debug C program

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

`vscode 1.67.2`

`native-debug 0.26.0`

I'm debugging an application written in C and would like to take a look at assembly instruction currently being executed. In native `gdb` we have `layout asm` command which allows us to step through all the assembly instructions using the `si` command.

So when opening debug console I tried to display assembly layout in there so I could see both source and compiled code. But `layout asm` didn't work:

[image]

**Is there a way to display compiled assembly code in a separate window to understand what instruction is currently being executed?**

Comment: Have you tried the [Disassembly View](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_59#_disassembly-view)?

Comment: @ssbssa Native-debug does not seem to support disassembly view.